# Dynamically generate ng-table template

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ng-table for nice sortable and filterable-by-column tables. Unfortunately as I am using it (pretty standard copy from how they do the demos) I have to write a bunch of HTML for each column in order to get filtering enabled. With some tables having dozens of columns this is REALLY tedious. Is there a way to generate the ng-table dynamically from the model rather than having to hand-code each table header?  This is a sample of my ng-table HTML:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" export-csv="csv" class="table table-bordered     table-hover table-condensed">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
        <td  data-title="'STUDYID'" filter="{ 'STUDYID': 'text' }" sortable="'STUDYID'">
          {{item.STUDYID}}
        </td>
        <td  data-title="'SITEID'" filter="{ 'SITEID': 'text' }" sortable="'SITEID'">
          {{item.SITEID}}
        </td>
        <td  data-title="'SUBJID'" filter="{ 'SUBJID': 'text' }" sortable="'SUBJID'">
          <a href="/profiles?subject={{item.SUBJID}}&study={{item.study_id}}&version={{item.version}}">{{item.SUBJID}}</a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
```

Basically, what I want is this, but with column-level filtering enabled:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Qt9FnE?p=preview

Thanks so much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Found a Plunker with the solution by EVILKOST, this works like a charm. The $scope.filter_dict can be left blank as I have dynamic columns a little loop in the controller fills in $scope.columns.

```
 $scope.columns = [
            { title: 'Name', field: 'name', visible: true, filter: { 'name': 'text' } },
            { title: 'Age', field: 'age', visible: true }
        ];
```

Great solution!
http://plnkr.co/edit/H5EoKuIsUU68OCrsRgS1?p=preview